# Sum of alternating elements of a list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to compute the sum of alternating elements of a list but it doesn't work the way it should and i can't find the problem... please help me.

If I have the list: [1,2,3,4] it should return 1-2+3-4 = -2.

This is my code:

```
poz(E,[],0):-!.
poz(E,L,N):-poz_aux(E,L,N,1).

poz_aux(E,[E|_],N,N).
poz_aux(E,[_|T],N,K):-
    K1 is K + 1,
    poz_aux(E,T,N,K1).

suma([],0).
suma(L,S):-suma_aux(L,S,L,0).

suma_aux([],S,_,S).
suma_aux([H|T],S,L,S1):-
    poz(H,L,P),
    P mod 2 = 1,
    S2 is S1 + H,
    suma_aux(T,S,L,S2).
suma_aux([H|T],S,L,S1):-
    poz(H,L,P),
    P mod 2 = 0,
    S2 is S1 - H,
    suma_aux(T,S,L,S2).
```

Answer (score 2):

Things like these can be better expressed with the program structure:

```
list_altsum([], 0).
list_altsum([A], S) :-
   S is A.
list_altsum([A,B|ABs],S0) :-
   list_alsum(ABs, S1),
   S0 is A-B+S1.
```

Alternatively:

```
list_altsum(Xs, S) :-
   list_altsum(Xs, 1, S).

list_altsum([], _, 0).
list_altsum([A|As], F0, S0) :-
   F1 is -F0,
   list_altsum(As, F1, S1),
   S0 is F0*A+S1.
```